# ArcGIS: Is there an alternative to JS' ImageryTileLayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

There's `ImageryTileLayer` in Javascript, but I was unable to find it in iOS SDK and documentation. Is there a way to make a layer with the same source URL in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer in the official ArcGIS community:

> The equivalent in ArcGIS Runtime is the AGSImageServiceRaster class,
> which you display via the AGSRasterLayer class:
>
> [Add raster data | ArcGIS Runtime API for iOS | ArcGIS Developers](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/layers/add-raster-data/#create-a-raster-from-an-image-service)
>
> [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS: AGSImageServiceRaster Class Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_image_service_raster.html)
>
> [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS: AGSRasterLayer Class Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_raster_layer.html)